# can't rdp to work desktop over vpn by name

Tags: domain-name-system, vpn, cisco-vpn, meraki

I have a couple of users that are having the same issue. They can VPN in to our local site but once the VPN is established they can only RDP to there desktop using the IP address. I have had a user test this and when they ping their work desktop from home, after the VPN connection is established, by IP address she gets a good return, but by desktop name she gets a "Request timed out." return and I noticed the address it has in brackets next to the name is nowhere near correct [198.105.254.63]. We have our local network set up as 10.101.x.x. Any idea why this could be and how I can fix this? The DNS IP's she is getting, after the VPN is connected, are correct.

Comment: Does the vpn user use the same dns server which is used in your office lan? Do your vpn is configured to deliver your office nameservers to the connected client?

Comment: Yes after she is VPN'd in she is using the same DNS server. Yes it is configured to send the nameservers to the client.

Comment: Are you using fully qualified domain names or just the computer name? Assuming reverse DNS is configured, can you test if DNS is working properly and get the fully qualified name by connecting to the VPN and using `nslookup IPADDRESS` where IPADDRESS is the IP address of the computer you attempting to remote into?

Comment: I will have her test nslookup tonight. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Can you run a tracert by IP and a nslookup for the hostname. I suspect either NAT over the VPN (rare) or a DNS suffix issue. Checking the tracert should help identify the IP's the data goes through and the nslookup will prove the DNS is resolving for the hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I guess your VPN clients are not using your Internal Office DNS servers when connected, and that's why can not resolve the internal hostnames correctly.

You need to make sure that you configure your VPN server so that the clients, when connected also recieve the internal namservers (those you use in Office lan). Then they will be able to resolve the names properly.

The hostnames that are used in LAN environment are not globally resolvable as they used some private ip addresses which are also not globally routable. The host/ipaddress information are configured and stored in local nameservers and that's why when using some other DNS server outside the LAN they are not resolvable.

Comment: I have had her check this with an ipconfig /all command in her cmd prompt and it appears the DNS server she is getting from the VPN connection is correct.

Comment: Can you also chek if they are used?

Comment: Sorry for the late response but yes you were correct. We were able to get her into her machine by IP.

Comment: Glad that it helped!